# How to use component in others?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have a component `TreeComponent`. It has no module. Just component anf template.

How to use this componnt in other components?

When I add component to declaration section of another component:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: ["TreeComponent"]
});
```

I get an error:

> Type TreeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Comment: Sholud I create module for ths component or register this component on the top of modules?

Comment: Register this component in your app.module.ts file only. Remove any other declarations.

Comment: But I need this component only in two componnent, and I dont want to load this component 
in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you have added `TreeComponent` to the `declarations` array of two Angular Modules.

Instead of doing that just export `TreeComponent` from a Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TreeComponent],
  exports: [TreeComponent]
})
export class MyCustomModule;
```

And then add your Module to the `imports` array of any other module in which you want to use this `TreeComponent`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MyCustomModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class MyOtherModule;
```

and

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MyCustomModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class SomeOtherModule;
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample Code Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-component-module) for your ref.

As of now, I've just added the `CustomComponentsModule` to the `imports` array of the `AppModule`. But you can also add `CustomComponentsModule` to the `imports` array of any Angular Module you want to use the `TreeComponent` in.

Comment: I can not export because `declarations: [TreeComponent],` says an error, two declarations

Comment: `MyCustomModule;` is it treeModule or another module?

Comment: So, you recomment  to wrap this in module?

Comment: I am not sure about `MyCustomModule` is it correct name?

Comment: I mean this module is related to tree component or it is extern module?

Comment: It is related to the `TreeComponent`. You can give it a relevant name. I've just named it `MyCustomModule` at the moment. I've also added a Sample Stackblitz for your ref. Hope that helps.